# CRUD em flutter

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart

Estou com uma duvida, que sei qual é o problema mas não tenho ideia de como resolver. Em um crud que fiz tenho um parâmetro `idade` que é int (Definido como `INTEGER` no banco) e não consigo cadastrar no banco mas se eu inserir de forma manual, fica tudo OK e quando vou editar somente a idade não edita ou ela edita de todos (não sei ao certo). Ja o excluir e listar estão OK.

Tela de cadastro:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:giphysearch/models/clienteModel.dart';
import 'package:giphysearch/pages/tarefa7cadastro.dart';
import 'package:scoped_model/scoped_model.dart';

  final _nomeController = TextEditingController();
  final _idadeController = TextEditingController();
  final _emailController = TextEditingController();

  num _numIdade = num.tryParse(_idadeController.text);  
  int intTryParse = int.tryParse(_idadeController.text);
class Cadastro extends StatefulWidget {

  final Cliente cliente;

  Cadastro({this.cliente});

  @override
  _CadastroState createState() => _CadastroState();
}

class _CadastroState extends State<Cadastro> {

  final _nameFocus = FocusNode();

  bool _userEdited = false;

  Cliente _editedCliente;
  ClienteHelper helper = ClienteHelper();

//Etse acusa o erro
//Aqui eu uso para testar a inserção no banco
 /*
 @override
 void initState(){
    super.initState();
   Cliente c = Cliente();
    c.nome = "nome";
    c.idade = 20;
    c.email = "email";
    helper.inserirCliente(c);

     /* helper.getAllClientes().then((list){
     print(list);
  });*/

 }*/


//Este é como se não reconhecesse 
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    if(widget.cliente == null){
      _editedCliente = Cliente();
    } else {
      _editedCliente = Cliente.fromMap(widget.cliente.toMap());

      _nomeController.text = _editedCliente.nome;
      _numIdade = _editedCliente.idade;
      _emailController.text = _editedCliente.email;
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: _requestPop,
      child:  ScopedModel<ClienteHelper>(
        model: ClienteHelper(),
        child: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("CRUD"),
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
        centerTitle: true,
      ),

        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: (){
            if(_editedCliente.nome != null && _editedCliente.nome.isNotEmpty){
              Navigator.pop(context, _editedCliente);
            } else {
              FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_nameFocus);
            }
          },
          child: Icon(Icons.save),
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        ),

        body: ScopedModelDescendant<ClienteHelper>(
          builder: (context, child, model){
            return  SingleChildScrollView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              TextField(
                controller: _nomeController,
                focusNode: _nameFocus,
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Nome"),
                onChanged: (text){
                  _userEdited = true;
                  setState(() {
                    _editedCliente.nome = text;
                  });
                },
              ),
              TextField(
                controller: _idadeController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Idade"),
                onChanged: (text){
                  _userEdited = true;
                  _editedCliente.idade = _numIdade;
                },
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              ),
              TextField(
                controller: _emailController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Email"),
                onChanged: (text){
                  _userEdited = true;
                  _editedCliente.email = text;
                },
                keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
          }
          )
        )


      ),
    );
  }

  Future<bool> _requestPop(){
    if(_userEdited){
      showDialog(context: context,
        builder: (context){
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text("Descartar Alterações?"),
            content: Text("Se sair as alterações serão perdidas."),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                child: Text("Cancelar"),
                onPressed: (){
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              ),
              FlatButton(
                child: Text("Sim"),
                onPressed: (){
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
              ),
            ],
          );
        }
      );
      return Future.value(false);
    } else {
      return Future.value(true);
    }
  }

}
```

Salvar cliente no banco:

```
//Salvando o Cliente noo banco
  Future<Cliente> inserirCliente(Cliente cliente)async{
    Database dbCliente = await db;
    cliente.id = await dbCliente.insert(clienteTable, cliente.toMap());
    return cliente;
  }
```

Update no banco:

```
  //Atualizar os dados do cliente
  Future<int>updateCliente(Cliente cliente)async{
    Database dbCliente = await db;
    return await dbCliente.update(clienteTable, cliente.toMap(), where: "$idColumn = ?", whereArgs: [cliente.id]);
  }
```

Acredito que o erro seja na tela de `Cadastro` (que é a mesma para o update) mas não consigo achar esse erro.

Comment: Ocorre algum erro ao tentar cadastrar um novo cliente? Ou simplesmente não salva a idade?

Answer (score 1):

Em relação a atualização da idade seu erro está na hora de setar o valor digitado para o _editedClient.idade, tente alterar para isso o TextField da idade:

```
  TextField(
    controller: _idadeController,
    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Idade"),
    onChanged: (text){
      _userEdited = true;
      _editedCliente.idade = text; // se a variável idade for int use int.parse(text)
    },
    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
  ),
```

na questão de salvar ou atualizar os dados da tabela, tente usar a função transaction, eu particularmente utilizo ela e não tenho problemas.
Tenta esse código, não testei pois estou no trabalho e fiz no notepad:

```
Future<Cliente> inserirCliente(Cliente cliente)async{
    Database dbCliente = await db;
    cliente.id = await dbCliente.transaction((txn) async {
        return await txn.rawInsert("INSERT INTO $clienteTable($NOME, $IDADE) VALUES('${cliente.nome}', '${cliente.idade}')");
    });
    return cliente;
  }
```

Para atualizar pode usar a mesma ideia só alterando o rawInsert para rawUpdate e alterar as condições para as de update.